# Tracking thread load in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

When designing an application with multiple moving parts that may be maxed out with a high load, it may be desirable to prioritize certain parts of the application over others. Also, knowing which part of the application is a bottleneck, or working the hardest, may be useful in determining the best for the application to react to the high load.

Is there a general way to determine load on a thread basis inside Java?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a textbook question..

Comment: Search Java profiler on google and you get a lot of them.

Comment: mre, It's not textbook question. I just chose not to write it in first person. Rajaganesh, I'm looking for how to do it inside the application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, if supported by the platform. From the [`ThreadMXBean` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html):

> A Java virtual machine implementation may support measuring the CPU time for the current thread, for any thread, or for no threads.

Here's some example code:

```
package test.thread.load;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class ThreadLoadTest
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        for (final long id : bean.getAllThreadIds())
        {
            System.out.println(bean.getThreadInfo(id).getThreadName()
                                  + ": " + bean.getThreadCpuTime(id));
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation for `OperatingSystemMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The design should clearly identify the different kind of task/use cases. Then depending on the need those task can be executed in a separated or main thread. You can have different thread pools for the different kind of tasks. Then run the different kind of load tests on the system to optimize the thread numbers and the associated queue size for the thread pools. Keep doing this exercise once you reach an optimal number and desired performance for your system.

Hope it helps!